# Generic master-detail component in TypeScript & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a generic master-detail component in TypeScript and React. The parent component should be responsible for the coordination between the master component and the detail component, i.e. pass the id of the item selected in the master to the detail. However, the master and detail components should not be hard-coded in the parent. This allows me to use the parent `MasterDetail` for different kind of entities. In summary, I would like to pass master and detail components as props, preferably as children.

Just for illustration, here's my hard-coded implementation (you can find a working version on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/master-detail-framework-lkvxb)):

```
const MasterDetail = () => {
  const [itemId, setItemId] = React.useState("");

  const handleClick = (itemId: string) => {
    setItemId(itemId);
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-flex p-2">
      <div className="lhs">
        <Master onClick={handleClick} />
      </div>
      <div className="flex-fill">
        <Detail itemId={itemId} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see, `Master` and `Detail` are hard-coded in this component. How do I pass them in as props in a TypeScript friendly manner?

I have mostly seen implementations using "Render Props", but that pattern seems to allow for only one child. Are there any patterns to extend this to multiple children?

Comment: `const MasterDetail = ({MasterComponent, DetailComponent}) => {`? The type for them would be dependent on the component `React.FC` for a functional component. `React.ComponentClass`... etc

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell. The types is what I was struggling with: whether they should be `React.FC` or `React.ReactNode`. Whatever I did, instantiating them in the body was giving me TypeScript errors. But I can try again with `React.FC`

Comment: Yep! [**heres your codesandbox updated with the types**](https://codesandbox.io/s/master-detail-framework-opnkd). Let me know if that isn't what you were looking for

Comment: Thank you!!! Very elegant. Can you please write a short answer and I will mark it as the correct solution?

Comment: Yep sure thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the `Master` and `Detail` components variable / dynamic then make them a prop that you can pass, so its more generic

usage would be `<MasterDetail MasterComponent={Master} DetailComponent={Detail} />`

Now, defining your types.. you have to be specific / make sure the types match up.

```
interface Props {
  DetailComponent: React.FC<DetailProps>;
  MasterComponent: React.FC<MasterProps>;
}

export const MasterDetail: React.FC<Props> = ({ DetailComponent, MasterComponent }) => {
  const [itemId, setItemId] = React.useState("");
  const handleClick = (itemId: string) => {
    setItemId(itemId);
  };

  return (
    <div className="d-flex p-2">
      <div className="lhs">
        <MasterComponent onClick={handleClick} />
      </div>
      <div className="flex-fill">
        <DetailComponent itemId={itemId} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Remember to define the different instances of your `Detail` component this way `export const Detail: React.FC<DetailProps> = ({ itemId }) => {` and you should be good

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.